# ggplot to create multi line plot from csv file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am completely new to ggplot (and to some extent R). I have been blown away with the quality of graphs that can be created using ggplot, and I am trying to learn how to create a simple multi line plot using ggplot.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any tutorials that help me get close to what I am trying to do:

I have a CSV file that contains the following data:

```
id,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6
30,0.841933670833,0.842101814883,0.842759547545,1.88961562347,1.99808377527,0.841933670833
40,1.47207692205,1.48713866811,1.48717177671,1.48729643008,1.48743226992,1.48713866811
50,0.823895293045,0.900091982861,0.900710334491,0.901274168324,0.901413662472,0.901413662472
```

I would like to plot:

1. the first column (id) on the X axis
2. each subsequent 'column' as a line plot, with smoothing between the points of the line to create a nice smooth line
3. A legend for f1, f2 ....
4. Specify a line colour and add marks (e.g. crosses i.e. '+') to the line plot for column f2 (for example).

I am really new to ggplot, so have really not got beyond reading the file into R.

Any help in getting me create the plot as describe above, will be very educational and help reduce the ggplot learning curve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 one line per each row dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894306/ggplot2-one-line-per-each-row-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(30L, 40L, 50L), f1 = c(0.841933670833, 
1.47207692205, 0.823895293045), f2 = c(0.842101814883, 1.48713866811, 
0.900091982861), f3 = c(0.842759547545, 1.48717177671, 0.900710334491
), f4 = c(1.88961562347, 1.48729643008, 0.901274168324), f5 = c(1.99808377527, 
1.48743226992, 0.901413662472), f6 = c(0.841933670833, 1.48713866811, 
0.901413662472)), .Names = c("id", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", 
"f6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

from here I would use `melt`.  Read `?melt.data.frame` for more info.  But in one sentence, this takes data from a "wide" format to a "long" format.

```
library(reshape2)
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars='id')

> dat.m
   id variable     value
1  30       f1 0.8419337
2  40       f1 1.4720769
3  50       f1 0.8238953
4  30       f2 0.8421018
5  40       f2 1.4871387
6  50       f2 0.9000920
7  30       f3 0.8427595
8  40       f3 1.4871718
9  50       f3 0.9007103
10 30       f4 1.8896156
11 40       f4 1.4872964
12 50       f4 0.9012742
13 30       f5 1.9980838
14 40       f5 1.4874323
15 50       f5 0.9014137
16 30       f6 0.8419337
17 40       f6 1.4871387
18 50       f6 0.9014137
>
```

then plot however you'd like:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=id, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data=dat.m[dat.m$variable=='f2',], cex=2)
```

Where `aes` defines the aesthetics such as the x value, y value, color/colour, etc.  Then you add "layers". in the previous example I've added a line for what I defined in the `ggplot()` portion with `geom_line()` and added a point with `geom_point` where I only put them on the `f2` variable.

below, I added a smoothed line with `geom_smooth()`.  See the documentation for a bit more info on what this is doing, `?geom_smooth`.

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=id, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  geom_point(data=dat.m[dat.m$variable=='f2',], shape=3)
```

or shapes for all. Here I put shape in the aesthetics of `ggplot()`. By putting them here they apply to all successive layers rather than having to specify them each time.  However, I can overwrite the values supplied in `ggplot()` in any later layer:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=id, y=value, colour=variable, shape=variable)) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data=dat, aes(x=id, y=f2, color='red'), size=10, shape=2)
```

However, a bit of `ggplot` understanding just takes time.  Work through some of the examples given in the documentation and on the `ggplot2` website.  If your experience is anything like mine, after fighting with it for a few days or weeks it will eventually click.  Regarding the data, if you assign your data to `dat`, the code will not change.  `dat <- read.csv(...)`.  I don't use `data` as a variable because it is a built in function.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the code. Alas, its as cryptic as I feared it would be. Can you please comment the code so that I can at least see where the 'requirements' 1 .. 2 in my question, are being implemented using ggplot?. Last but not the least, in your code, you built the dataframe by hand. I will be reading the data from file into a dataframe using `data <- read.csv(file="myfile.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",");`. How will the code above change to allow me to account for the fact that the data is read from file as opposed to created on the fly?

Comment: the OP asked for smooth interpolation between the points (à la Excel??); I don't know of any really easy way to do this -- `geom_smooth` is a smoother, not a smooth interpolator. (I prefer the standard linear interpolation because I think it is more "true" to the data, although that's obviously a matter of aesthetics & interpretation ...)