# ggplot2 one line per each row dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I have a CSV file that contains the following data:

```
user,Measurement1,Measurement2,Measurement3,group
1,0.1,0.7,0.2,3
2,0.3,0.3,0.4,2
3,0.3,0.3,0.4,2
```

I need to plot one line per each user. The x axis can be just 1,2,3 (one point per each measurement labeled as before,at,after, but I can work out the labeling later). The color will be set by the group columns
I found [a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751047/ggplot-to-create-multi-line-plot-from-csv-file) similar to the one I need but I don't want to use the user code as the x value.

Comment: Note: rather than type in your data, use the `dput` function - others can then copy and past into their R console so they can work on your actual data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ggplot` likes data in the 'long' format: i.e., a column for every dimension, and a row for every observation. Your data is currently 'wide'. Use the `reshape` package to go from one to the other.

Do I understand correctly that you want Measurement1, Measurement2, and Measurement3 to be on the x-axis? (So that, in your data, user 1's line would go from 0.1 to 0.7 to 0.2? If so, you want something like this:

```
require(reshape)

#Recreate your data frame
user <- gl(3, 1)
Meas1 <- c(0.7, 0.3, 0.3)
Meas2 <- c(0.7, 0.3, 0.3)
Meas3 <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.4)
group <- c(3, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(user=user, Meas1=Meas1, Meas2=Meas2, Meas3=Meas3, group=group)

#'melt' the data frame into long format
dfm <- melt(df, id.vars=c("user", "group"))

ggplot(dfm, aes(x=as.numeric(variable), y=value, colour=user)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Drew, very useful, I am using melt as you said for the reshaping of the data and group for the plot:       ggplot(mdataFiltered, aes(x=Time, y=RR)) +
     geom_line(aes(group=user), alpha=0.3, linetype=3) + 
     opts(title='Plot by user') + facet_grid(facets=.~typeOfUser)