# How to insert a legend in density plot with qplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am completely new to R, and want to insert a simple *colored box legend* identifying each distribution as "data.1" and "data.2", in the following `qplot` plotting function (from the `ggplot2` package):

```
> V1 <- matrix(unlist(rnorm(200,-0.2,1)))
> V2 <- matrix(unlist(rnorm(200,0.3,4)))
> m <- data.frame(V1,V2)
> qplot(V1, main="Observed distr.", data=m,
geom='density',xlab="x",ylab="count",fill=I('green'), alpha=I(.5)) +
geom_density(aes(V2),data=m,fill='red', alpha=I(.5))
```

I have found solutions for `ggplot` but nothing for `qplot` with `geom='density'`. The curves are well drawn but no legend appears.
I would accept any solution that gives me a density plot with transparency, labelled axes, a title and a colored box legend. Thank you.

Comment: Imho: Forget about `qplot`, use `ggplot`: `library(tidyverse);ggplot(m %>% gather, aes(value, fill = key)) + geom_density(alpha = .5) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red"), labels = c("V1" = "myV1"))`. I guess that will be they way to go anyway [in the future](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/): _"the use of qplot() in examples has been grealy reduced. This is inline with the 2nd edition of the ggplot2 book, which eliminates qplot() in favour of ggplot()."_

Comment: @lukeA: yes, I am beginning to see the light on this. I am done with `qplot`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12906555/4552295) put it *"ggplot likes data in the 'long' format: i.e., a column for every dimension, and a row for every observation"*. So we `melt` the `data.frame`

```
require(ggplot2)
require(data.table)
set.seed(10) # this is so you get the same numbers from rnorm.
m <- data.frame(V1 = matrix(unlist(rnorm(200, -0.2, 1))),
                V2 = matrix(unlist(rnorm(200, 0.3, 4))))

m <- melt(m) # This comes from data.table, yet, many alt. ways to achieve this
head(m)
  variable       value
1       V1 -0.18125383
2       V1 -0.38425254
3       V1 -1.57133055
4       V1 -0.79916772
5       V1  0.09454513
6       V1  0.18979430

ggplot(data = m, aes(value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you snoram. Exactly what I needed. Cheers.