# ggplot individual line plots upon group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to plot the same line plot from a table with groups.
I tried to adapt after this: [ggplot to create multi line plot from csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751047/ggplot-to-create-multi-line-plot-from-csv-file) but it did not work out for me.

Data structure:

```
structure(list(X__1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10"), ID2 = c("abc-0001", "abc-0001", "abc-0001", "abc-0001", 
"abc-0002", "abc-0002", "abc-0002", "abc-0002", "abc-0002", "abc-0002"
), domes = c("23", "23", "24", "6", "12", "10", "8", "14", "21", 
"30"), days = c("0.0", "26.0", "27.0", "37.0", "0.0", "3.0", 
"14.0", "25.0", "40.0", "47.0")), .Names = c("X__1", "ID2", "colonies", 
"days"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

My current code:

```
ggplot(test3, aes(x=days, y=colonies, fill=ID2, color=ID2,group=ID2)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    geom_point(data=test3, aes(x=days, y=colonies)) +
    theme_bw() + 
    labs(
        x = "days",
        y = "colonies")
```

What I would love to get is individual plots for the groups abc- but the list extends further so i would love to have it applied to all "ID2" groups.
Hope this makes sense for you.
Doing everything seperately and run multiplot would take forever and I would need to adapt all of the code to get correct plots once the data gets updated.
If possible the Legend/Title should change according to the group.
Thank you so much!
 Dennis

Comment: All your columns appear to be character values. Seems like you might not have read your data correctly. There are things that looks like numbers but are not numeric. This will cause a problem with ggplot.

Comment: thanks. I was running in this issue but solved it when I reshaped my tables and reloaded them into r.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to plot multiple lines, grouping by the ID2 column?

So you could try:

```
ggplot(test3) +
geom_line(aes(days, colonies) +
facet_wrap(~ ID2)
```

Facet wrap achieves what I think you're after.

Comment: you miss a ')' in geom_line. I also feel like @MrFlick is right about numeric and character variables

Comment: thanks so much! this helped a lot and saved me from searching and trying 100 more things!!! :)

Comment: only error that I get is: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
but the graphs show up. Is there a way to change the style of the heading from the groups?

Comment: Did you convert the aes parameters to numeric? As in 
    aes(as.numeric(days), as.numeric(colonies))

Comment: That was what was being discussed by @MrFlick